# Main window disappears behind other application's windows after a sub window uses ShowDialog on a third window

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, window, modal-dialog

I have noticed this very odd behavior in a WPF application.

I have a `MainWindow`, which is shown using `Show()` from `App.OnStartup`. Said `MainWindow` can open a (non-modal) `SubWindow`, also using `Show()`. `SubWindow`'s `Owner` is set to `MainWindow`.

When `SubWindow` is closed, `MainWindow` is visible again (good).

Some actions can cause the `SubWindow` to open a third window as a modal dialog, using `ShowDialog()` (`Owner` is set to `SubWindow`). When that modal dialog is opened and closed at least once during the lifetime of a `SubWindow`, then the weird thing happens.

After closing `SubWindow`, `MainWindow` does not come into view. Instead, whatever random window is *behind* `MainWindow` comes into view. Can anyone explain to me why this happens, and how to fix it?

It makes no difference whether the modal dialog is a normal `Window` displayed using `ShowDialog()`, or a message box shown using `MessageBox.Show()`.

---

Here is some *minimal* code to reproduce this. Create a new WPF application in visual studio, and paste this into the pre-generated MainWindow.xaml.cs

Then, press a key on the keyboard to open only one window, close it, behavior as expected. Press two keys, close both, then the very first window is behind Visual Studio (presumably).

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.PreviewKeyDown += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (this.Owner is MainWindow)
        {
            // we're the SubWindow

            MessageBox.Show("I am a modal dialog");

            // code below produces the exact same behavior as the message box

            //var dialog = new MainWindow();
            //dialog.Owner = this;
            //dialog.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            // we're the initial MainWindow created by App.
            var subWindow = new MainWindow();
            subWindow.Owner = this;
            subWindow.Show();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Excellent question. And well stated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a pretty annoying WPF bug, I never did find the flaw in the code that causes it but there's a heckofalot of "gotta figure this out" comments in the source code that deals with focusing.  Just a workaround, a less than ideal one, you can solve it by explicitly giving the focus to the owner when the window is closing.  Copy/paste this code in your SubWindow class;

```
    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
        base.OnClosing(e);
        if (!e.Cancel && this.Owner != null) this.Owner.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: For what it's worth we saw this bug in a plain WinForms (.NET 2) application I worked on about 5 years ago. I've just run into it again today in a new project (.NET 4.5). I seem to remember the bug hinges on having `Show()` nested 2-deep or more. Looks like other people have run into it too ([here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/vbulletin-2005-windows-app-goes-back-z-order-after-dialog-box-clo-t3140486.html) and [here](http://web1.codeproject.com/Messages/1813163/Application-Goes-to-Back-of-ZOrder-after-cloasing-.aspx)); if I recall we used a workaround like @Hans suggests.

Comment: Just to let you know, your code causes an infinite loop. I can only imagine that `base.OnClosing` is a virtual function that is implemented in the method you are calling, hence calling itself.

Comment: Another thing, handling `Closing` event does not solve the problem for me - I needed to handle the `Closed` event.

Comment: AFAIK the Window.Closing event fires AFTER the override, so e.Cancel could be set afterwards which keeps the window open but the owner is focused anyway.
Using Closed is a possible workaround but does not avoid the problem in some cases :(

Comment: On my system - .Net 4.6.1, Win 7, this works for about 98-99% of the times. Unfortunately, 1% of failure makes it unsuitable for production code.

Comment: Many thanks. This works well on my system .NET 4.8, Windows 10.

Comment: Not that anybody cares anymore but I might have found the culprit. Normally, it is crucial that `EnableWindow` is called on the previously disabled (parent) window **before** the popup dialog is destroyed. A correctly functioning, modal message loop will do this. It's well-known that the dialog's WndProc is expected to set some flag to exit the modal loop (e.g. `EndDialog`). **But**, one pitfall is that the default `WM_CLOSE` must be suppressed (I think it currently isn't), otherwise the dialog's own WndProc will `DestroyWindow` itself. That's too early and will mess up the activated window.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread, but I tried all of these solutions (and many other more in other threads) and none of them worked. I didn't want to set my main window as the subwindow's `Owner` because I wanted to be able to minimize the subwindow.

What worked for me was to change the `WindowState` property in the main window instead.

This is how I do it, in my mainwindow.cs:

```
//create new window instance
subWindow = new SubWindow();

//event called on the mainwindow, after the subwindow has been closed. 
subWindow.Closed += (sender, args) =>
{
    subWindow = null; //clears the variable, so I can re-open the window later
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal; //this shows the main window!
};

//show subwindow
subWindow.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hit the same problem only with hiding the window.  I can't see that there is an equivalent event to Closing in this situation, but anyway this works:

```
        if (Owner != null) Owner.Focus();
        Hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

this.Owner.Focus(); is not working for me it still goes to the window behind I had to play around a bit much and tried to used TopMost, the problem with TopMost is I needed to return it to false after the close with it. I used both OnClosing and OnClosed event.

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosing(e);
    if (!e.Cancel && this.Owner != null) this.Owner.TopMost = true;
}

protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);
    if (this.Owner != null)
    {
        this.Owner.TopMost = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in WinFoms (.NET 4.7+). My workaround was closing the first dialog first (calling its `Close` method) and show the second dialog afterwards.

**Example**

1. Main form opens `FirstForm`
2. `FirstForm` opens `SecondForm` and causes the problem!

**Workaround**

Call `Close` method inside the `FirstForm` which will be going to open the `SecondForm`:

```
// FirstForm.cs

using(var secondForm = new SecondForm())
{
    Close(); // <- this closes FirstForm instance
    secondForm.ShowDialog(owner: mainFormInstance);
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I figured I would share what worked for my C# WinForms application since Owner.Focus() did not work for me.

It's a variation on the TopMost fix from Daren, but I found that I don't actually have to set TopMost to true and back.  Just setting it to itself does the trick of keeping the parent window from disappearing behind other applications.

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e) {
    if (Owner != null)
        Owner.TopMost = Owner.TopMost;
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```